# Adding Mean and Whiskers to a DotPlot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have a dotplot made up of the following data.frame:

```
        Hotel  room   cost
        <int> <chr> <dbl>
 1          1 room1 171. 
 2          2 room2 622. 
 3          3 room3 247. 
 4          4 room4 354. 
 5          1 room1 175. 
 6          2 room2 955. 
 7          3 room3 193. 
 8          4 room4 286. 
 9          1 room1 884. 
10          2 room2 861. 
11          3 room3 798. 
12          4 room4 879. 
13          1 room1  27.3
14          2 room2 355. 
15          3 room3  43.2
16          4 room4 391.
```

Using this code:

```
  ggplot(dummy.data, aes(x=room, y=cost, fill = hotel)) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize = 1.5) + 
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20))
```

[image]

I wan to add the mean cost of each room across the four hotels and then have whiskers extending in the opposite direction. The options I have found online keep putting the mean lines across each individual dot, probably due to me using "fill = hotel."

Any help would be appreciative.

Comment: Do you mean adding a vertical line showing min max and mean for all rooms?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. But when I have tried stat_summary, it isn't calculating it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help you (mean is in blue):

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df <- structure(list(Hotel = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), room = c("room1", "room2", "room3", 
"room4", "room1", "room2", "room3", "room4", "room1", "room2", 
"room3", "room4", "room1", "room2", "room3", "room4"), cost = c(171, 
622, 247, 354, 175, 955, 193, 286, 884, 861, 798, 879, 27.3, 
355, 43.2, 391)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16"))

#Code
#Create summary
df %>% group_by(room) %>% 
  mutate(min=min(cost,na.rm=T),max=max(cost,na.rm=T),avg=mean(cost,na.rm=T)) -> df2

#Plot
ggplot(df2, aes(x=room, y=cost, fill = factor(Hotel))) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize = 1.5) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = min, ymax = max), width = 0.5,size=1)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = min, ymax = avg), width = 0.5,size=1)+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to add the mean bar without using the stat_summary function? Like, is there an alternative with something such as geom_crossbar, where I just manually give it the mean values for each of the rooms? Stat_summary just isn't working for me (the dummy I gave isn't the exactly data I am using, but close.)

Comment: @bioinformatics2020 I have updated the code avoiding `stat_sum` and making a trick with another `geom_errorbar`. Check if this works for you.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  Appreciative! This gives me some incentive to learn more about stat_summary() haha